# Store a listview in mysql sever using web service

Tags: php, android, web-services, listview, retrofit

i have a listview like this

[image]

i want to store the content a the listview in mysql  server
i dont have the webservice yet
any help

Comment: image link is not working , and you are gona need web service for that.

Comment: it works now ? @AbdulKawee ?
right now i asking for the class android that can send the content of the listview

Comment: where do you want to send the content? to server ? and save it in mySQL db?

Comment: What kind of server do you have? Or do you wanna have? The Android class you have to use depends on your server type.

Comment: Have you ever read some pages on this site? You can read every day here how people do it.

Comment: @AbdulKawee i want to save in mySQL db

Comment: @Somoud then you are going to need a `backend api` , which will receive data from android and store it in `mySQL db`

Comment: do you have any class exemple that i can start with, then i will buil the `backend api` @AbdulKawee

Comment: you can use both `volley` or `Retrofit` for that purpose , they are easy to use. let me share some code spinets

Answer (score 0):

First add dependencies in your build.gradle(app) file

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

make a class name ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {


public static final String BASE_URL = "https://example.com/api/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

private static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(){
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();
    return okClient;
}

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(getOkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
 }

}
```

and interface named ApiService

```
public interface APIService {

 @POST("Example/get_simple_listing")
   Call<Main_Model> getMarqueesLists(
  );

}
```

and then simply

```
 public APIService service;
 service = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIService.class);
 Call<Bookirea_MainModel> userCall = service.getMarqueesLists();
    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Bookirea_MainModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Bookirea_MainModel> call, Response<Bookirea_MainModel> response) {
            if (response.body().getStatus()==1){




            }
            else {
                Log.d("ResponceFromServer" ,"Responce" +response.body().getMessage());
                //Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, ""+response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Bookirea_MainModel> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d("ResponceFromServer" ,"Responce OnFailure" +t.toString());

        }
    });
```

You can have a look at [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-in-android-ed47aef01ecb) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) link for detail's.

Hope this helps